# Generating Heatmap from PostGIS

Tags: postgis, google-maps, leaflet

I have GIS data in a PostGIS data base and would like to generate a density map and display them on a Leaflet/Google Maps.

**Question:** What is the recommended/typical method for doing so, without transferring ALL (millions) the data points within the map's viewpoint to the Leaflet/Gmaps map? No user intervention (ie. Import data into ArcGIS to generate the map) should be required unless automation is possible via CLI etc.

Currently using Postgresql/PostGIS as the spatial database and Leaflet on the browser.

[image]

Comment: Check out this thread: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2011-December/031578.html. They suggested to use R (with python or perl bindings) and provided some code examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try using middleware such as Geoserver which can generate heatmaps for you:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/rendering-transform.html#heatmap-generation

Comment: Geoserver looks awesome! Any idea how we can get the value at a specific point on the heatmap? *(eg: in the screenshot in original post)*